# how i can create a .config file to my CNN using a model.pb, model.h5 or model.json?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

i am new in this area. So, can you guys help how to create a .config file for a CNN ?

Passing a documentation of how doing this or a tutorial will be helping me a lot. thanks guys.

Comment: [This](https://gogul09.github.io/software/flower-recognition-deep-learning) might be helpful. They create a configuration JSON file and call it during the training.

Answer (score 1):

This question does not make much sense to me since `.config` is not a standard output file of Keras. Maybe you are confusing it with `Model.get_config()` method which outputs a dictionary (that can be saved as .json) and can be loaded as `model = Model.from_config(config)`

Could you provide any reference to the `.config` file you are talking about?

Edit:

If what you want is just some way to serialize your model:

```
import json
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')
config = model.get_config()
print(config)
with open('model.json', 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(config, f)
```

Comment: I think he meant a file containing configuration of a CNN network, like number of layers, number of filters etc.

Comment: Well, afaik, the closest to that in keras is model.get_config() anyway... Is there anything like the .proto in caffe for keras?

Comment: the example a got is from this file in github  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_ava_v2.1.config

Comment: @GabrielBorinMacedo That .config is something specific to the tensorflow object detection framework, it doesn't tell you anything about the model other than which preset to use. It is a nicer way the tensorflow folks chose instead of relying on cli parameters to set your training hyperparameters